# Unbalanced logistic regression: correction for intercept term and report

Tags: regression, logistic, unbalanced-classes, intercept

I am trying to run a logistic regression with one class (class 0, n = 513) over-represented compared to the other one (class 1, n = 173).

So far, in order to correct for the biased intercept, I just resampled the class 0 in order to get n = 173, then ran a logistic regression, then stocked the estimates. Finally I calculated the median of all these coefficient.

The issue I have is that I am not so sure my method is correct, and I am not so sure how I could report z values and other stats usually obtained in summary of glm.

Comment: How is the model performing? Misclassification error/ AUC

Comment: Your assumption is that half of the population is in class 0. I am pretty sure that is incorrect, and that your original estimate of the constant is as unbiased as possible, while your "correction" actually introduces a significant bias to your estimate.